# how to fix wrong encoding in translation application?

Tags: java, translation, urlencode

I implemented some translational application and faced with the problem - incorrect output.

For example:

Input:

> "Three predominant stories interweave: a dynastic war among several
>   families for control of Westeros; the rising threat of the dormant
>   cold supernatural Others dwelling beyond an immense wall of ice on
>   Westeros' northern border; and the am"

Output:

> "%0D%0A%0D%0AThe+история+ -
>   +A+Песня+из+Лед+и+Fire+принимает++++вымышленный+континентах+Вестероса+и+Essos%2C+with+a+история++тысяч++лет.++Точка+++++главе+в+в+история+
>   - +a+ограниченной+перспектива+++ассортимент++символы+,+растет+from+девяти+в+в+первое++тридцать
>   один+++пятый+of+the+романов.+Три+преобладающим+рассказы+переплетаются%3A+a+династические+war+среди+несколько+семей+for+control++Вестероса%3B++рост+угрозу+of+the+спящие+cold+сверхъестественное+Другие+жилье+за+an+огромный+wall++лед+on+Вестероса%27+сев.
>   границы%3B+и++am"

I know that URLEncoder is the reason of wrong output (all these "+" and "%"), but don't know how to fix it.

Here is some code:

```
        // This method should take an original text that should be 
        // translated and encode it to use as URL parameter.


     private String encodeText(String text) throws IOException {
                return URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8"); 
            } 

    // It shold “extract” translated text from Yandex Translator response. 
    // More details about response format you can find at 
    // http://api.yandex.ru/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate.xml, 
    // we need to use XML interface.

        private String parseContent(String content)
                    throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
                String begin = "<text>";
                String end = "</text>";
                String result = "";
                int i, j;
                i = content.indexOf(begin);
                j = content.indexOf(end);
                if ((i != -1) && (j != -1)) {
                    result = content.substring((i + begin.length()), j);
                }
                return new String(result.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
            }

 // method translate() should return translation of original text.
 // urlSourceProvider loads translated text   
        public String translate(String original) throws IOException {
                return parseContent(urlSourceProvider
                        .load(prepareURL(encodeText(original))));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode(variable, "UTF-8");
```

it should decode your text.